# variable substitution querying postgres jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Hi I am querying a JSONb object where the search key depends on the value of another key/value pair. Consider the following example:

```
select 
'{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->'a',--b,
('{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->'a')::text,--"b"
'{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->('{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->'a')::text--null, desired output is 2
```

Somehow I need to dereference the "b" to a json search path like 'b'

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tu use `->>` operator instead `->`. There was unwanted double quoting:

```
select 
'{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->'a',--b,
 ('{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->>'a')::text,--"b"
'{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->('{"a":"b","b":2}'::jsonb->>'a')::text;
```